# What is the right way to self-host a Web API?

Tags: c#, android, wcf, asp.net-web-api, owin

I'm not asking for a best practice advice since there are numerous blog posts and tutorials about the topic all over the internet.

I'm asking out of confusion since Microsoft made a lot of change to the whole self hosting procedure and every tutorial I find take a different, deprecated or unfamiliar approach.

My goal is to set up a self hosted *Web API* in a legacy Windows Service to control various long running tasks from a non-Windows client, such as an Android application where integrating a *WCF* / *SOAP* client can really be a PITA.

I'm aware about the fact that *WCF* is capable of offering a RESTful service, but since Web API is really suited for such a task, I thought I gave it a shot.

This is how I currently start my API hosted using *OWIN* (*Katana*):

```
public class ApiBootstrap {

    var httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
    // ... configure routes etc.

    appBuilder.UseWebApi(httpConfiguration);     // appBuilder = IAppBuilder
    var disposable = WebApp.Start<ApiBootstrapper>(_myBaseUri);

}
```

But most tutorials go on a different approach:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:999");
// ... configure routes etc..

var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
server.OpenAsync().Wait();
```

Now, I understand the `HttpSelfHostServer` class is from `System.Web.Http.SelfHost` and not using *OWIN*, and both work fine.

But I'm struggling for days to achieve very simple tasks such as securing the connection using *SSL*, creating authorization etc., just because every tutorial I find on those topics referr to the self hosted method not using *OWIN*. But AFAIK, *OWIN* (*Katana*) is Microsofts prefered approach to achieve self hosting.

As a beginner, I am completely confused and helpless!

***Edit**: 4 upvotes, 1 fav and 30 views in only 6 minutes but still no answer. Can't really say if I'm doing genious coffee stuff here or if it's just an incredible dumb question.*

Comment: Comment on the edit: I'm guessing it's because you're treading pretty new ground here. OWIN as preferred approach by MS hasn't been that for a very long time, am I right? I'm also not sure that what you say are "very simple tasks" are in fact that. It may be that the answer to this question is "it cannot be done. Use IIS".

Comment: @Nilzor Yes, this could be the case, too. I already thought about using IIS to expose a Web API, but the problem is that I need a constantly running service for doing CPU intensive tasks. I could separate the service from the api by implementing a WCF host and access it via e.g. a MVC web application (which also offers the API), but a WCF client in MVC is also a real pain in my experience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HttpSelfHostServer is now marked as legacy on Nuget.  However, the Owin HTTPListener has only been RTM for a fairly short period of time now.

Also, part of the intent of Owin to ensure that how you setup middleware is identical regardless of how you host.  So you will not likely see many articles targeting Owin HttpListener hosting directly because it should be irrelevant which host you are using.

The OwinHttpListener currently uses the standard .net HttpListener under the covers, which in reality is the same thing that the HttpSelfHostServer used.  Therefore stuff like SSL should be configured in pretty much the same way.

As far as authentication is concerned, have you looked at Microsoft.Owin.Security, most likely everything you need is in there.

Comment: Please add example of using OwinHttpListener

Comment: I do not know how to migrate from HttpSelfHostServer to OwinHttpListener